# Draw an automaton with more states and bent arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I want to draw this automaton:

[image]

But I drew it with a bad way !!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,semithick]
\node[initial,state] (A) {$1$};
\node[state] (B) [right of=A] {$2$};
\node[state] (C) [right of=B] {$3$};
\node[state] (D) [right of=C] {$4$};
\node[state,accepting] (E) [right of=D] {$5$};
\node[state,accepting] (F) [below of=E] {$6$};
\node[state,accepting] (G) [below of=D] {$7$};
\node[state,accepting] (H) [below of=G] {$8$};
\node[state,accepting] (I) [below of=H] {$9$};
\node[state] (J) [below of=A] {$10$};
\node[state,accepting] (P) [below of=J] {$16$};
\node[state] (K) [below left of=I] {$11$};
\node[state] (L) [right of=K] {$12$};
\node[state,accepting] (M) [right of=L] {$13$};
\node[state,accepting] (N) [below of=L] {$14$};
\node[state,accepting] (O) [below of=M] {$15$};
\node[state,accepting] (Q) [below of=B] {$17$};
\path (A) edge node {X}(B)
          edge node{I} (C)
          edge node{V} (J)
      (B) edge [loop above] node {X}(B)
          edge node{I} (C)
          edge node{V} (J)
          edge node{<>I,<>V} (Q)
      (C) edge node {X}(H)
          edge node{I} (D)
          edge node{V} (G)
          edge node{Autre} (I)
      (D) edge node {I}(E)
          edge node{<>I} (F)
      (J) edge node {I}(K)
          edge node{<>I} (P)
      (K) edge node {I}(L)
          edge node{<>I} (N)
      (L) edge node {I}(M)
          edge node{<>I} (O);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can use `edge[bend left]` etc.

Comment: How can I draw a transition between state 1 and 3 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add `bend left` or `bend right` or `bend left=<degree>` or `bend right=<degree>` to the `edge`s. Here is an example:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid]
  \node[state,initial]   (q_0)                {$q_0$};
  \node[state]           (q_1) [right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
  \node[state,accepting] (q_2) [right=of q_1] {$q_2$};
  \path[->] (q_0) edge                node [above] {0} (q_1)
                  edge [loop above]   node         {1} ()
                  edge [bend left=45] node [below] {1} (q_2)
                  edge [bend right]   node [below] {0} (q_2)
            (q_1) edge                node [above] {1} (q_2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: For completeness, could you also add workarounds for inserting `<>` and placing labels? :) [I have already +1ed this answer though.]

Comment: Try this: `\texttt{<>}`

Comment: Hey! I know! I wanted the OP and anybody searching for similar things to know. :P

Comment: How can I deplace the state 11 to the left ?like the first automaton

Comment: @user29570: you can use coordinates to put nodes, like `\node[state] (K) at (<x>, <y>) {$11$};`

Comment: thank you ,but what should I put in <x> and <y>..?Can I use this :\node[state] (K) [below left=5cm of=I] {$11$}; ?

Comment: @user29570: Try `\path (I) +(<x_offset>, <y_offset>) node[state] (K) {$11$};`

Comment: I used this: \node[state] (K) [below right of=P] {$11$}; and the issue is solved ,now I want deplace the automaton to the left of the page ,what should I do ?

Comment: @user29570: I'm not sure if this is what you want: Add a line `\noindent\hskip -1cm` before `\begin{tikzpicture}`. You can change `-1cm` to a suitable value.

Comment: thank you,and to deplace the automaton up ?

Comment: @user29570: Add a line `\vskip -1cm` before `\noindent\hskip -1cm`. BTW, if you add `\usetikzpackage{positioning}`, you can use relative position like this: `[below left=5cm of I]`.

Comment: I added \vskip -2cm ,but the automaton still in the same place !!!

Comment: Maybe this works: `\hbox{}\vskip -1cm`

Answer (score 4):

quite late, but here is your answer ;)

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,semithick]
\node[state,initial] (A) {$1$};
\node[state] (B) [right of=A] {$2$};
\node[state] (C) [right of=B] {$3$};
\node[state] (D) [right of=C] {$4$};
\node[state,accepting] (E) [right of=D] {$5$};
\node[state,accepting] (F) [below of=E] {$6$};
\node[state,accepting] (G) [below of=D] {$7$};
\node[state,accepting] (H) [below of=G] {$8$};
\node[state,accepting] (I) [below of=H] {$9$};
\node[state] (J) [below of=A] {$10$};
\node[state,accepting] (P) [below of=J] {$16$};
\node[state] (K) [below left of=I] {$11$};
\node[state] (L) [right of=K] {$12$};
\node[state,accepting] (M) [right of=L] {$13$};
\node[state,accepting] (N) [below of=L] {$14$};
\node[state,accepting] (O) [below of=M] {$15$};
\node[state,accepting] (Q) [below of=B] {$17$};
\path[->] 
      (A) edge [bend left=45] node {$X$}(B)
          edge [bend left=80] node{$I$} (C)
          edge node{$V$} (J)
      (B) edge [loop above] node {$X$}(B)
          edge [bend left=45] node {$I$} (C)
          edge node {$V$} (J)
          edge node {$<>I,<>V$} (Q)
      (C) edge [bend left=-5] node {$X$} (H)
          edge [bend left=45] node {$I$} (D)
          edge [bend left=15] node {$V$} (G)
          edge [bend left=-25] node {Autre} (I)
      (D) edge [bend left=45] node {$I$}(E)
          edge node {$<>I$} (F)
      (J) edge [bend left=15] node {$I$}(K)
          edge node {$<>I$} (P)
      (K) edge [bend left=45] node {$I$}(L)
          edge node {$<>I$} (N)
      (L) edge [bend left=45] node {$I$}(M)
          edge node{$<>I$} (O);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: here is the result]